# Vuejs: Exclude last played sound from array of sounds

Tags: javascript, vue.js, audio, vuejs3

I'm trying to randomize the sounds that I play when clicking on a button, but I also wanted to skip the last played sound. For example, if `Sfx4` will be played four times in a row it won't sound natural. I want to always play a new sound (within these 5 sounds of course). What I'm doing wrong? Give me some ideas on how to implement it if possible.

```
<template>
    <button class="book__nav-btn" @click="playTurnSfx">
        <slot> </slot>
    </button>
</template>

<script setup>
import { ref, computed, onMounted } from 'vue';
import Sfx1 from '@/assets/sounds/page-turn-1.mp3?url';
import Sfx2 from '@/assets/sounds/page-turn-2.mp3?url';
import Sfx3 from '@/assets/sounds/page-turn-3.mp3?url';
import Sfx4 from '@/assets/sounds/page-turn-4.mp3?url';
import Sfx5 from '@/assets/sounds/page-turn-5.mp3?url';

const sounds = [Sfx1, Sfx2, Sfx3, Sfx4, Sfx5];
const lastPlayedIndex = ref(null);
let playableSounds = sounds.toSpliced(lastPlayedIndex.value, 1);
const randomIndex = computed(() => {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * playableSounds.length);
});

const playTurnSfx = () => {
    const sound = new Audio(sounds[randomIndex.value]);
    sound.volume = 0.1;
    sound.play();
};
</script>
```

Comment: `lastPlayedIndex` and `playableSounds` never change once created

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always keep track of what the latest value was, filter it out from the array (don't worry, the original array will not change, you will get a copy of the array via filter, but without the items that did not match your criteria) and randomize the result:

```js
let sounds = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'];
let previous = -1;

function randomize() {
    let randIndex = parseInt(Math.random() * (sounds.length - ((sounds.indexOf(previous) >= 0) ? 1 : 0)));
    console.log(previous = sounds.filter(item => (item !== previous))[randIndex]);
}
```

```html
<input type="button" value="randomize" onclick="randomize()">
```

EDIT

Looked into the try inside the second edit to the question and this is how I made it to work (I ignore the sound-playing, we need to fix the logic that determines which sound is to be played, so here it's safe to asume that playing sounds works):

```js
const sounds = ['Sfx1', 'Sfx2', 'Sfx3', 'Sfx4', 'Sfx5'];
let previous = null;

const getRand = () => {
    const filteredSounds = sounds.filter(item => item !== previous);
    return filteredSounds[Math.floor(Math.random() * filteredSounds.length)];
};

const playSfx = () => {
    //const sound = new Audio(sounds[randIndex]);
    //sound.volume = 0.1;
    //sound.play();
    previous = getRand();
    console.log(previous);
};

for (let i = 0; i < 20; i++) playSfx();
```

The logical mistake that you made while trying to apply this idea was to, after correctly filtering your array and getting a random index, you took the sound corresponding the index just randomized from the unfiltered array rather than the filtered array.

So, if `previous` was `Sfx2`, for example, then your filter resulted in an array like `[Sfx1, Sfx3, Sfx4, Sfx5]`, but your initial array remained `[Sfx1, Sfx2, Sfx3, Sfx4, Sfx5]`, so if you get a random integer between 0..3, which happens to be 1, then `filteredSounds[1]` will be `Sfx3`, which differs from `previous`, which was `Sfx2` in this scenario, whereas `sounds[1]` is still `Sfx2`, so you need to get the value at the randomized index of `filteredSounds` rather than the unfiltered `sounds`.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. What's the point of writing `sounds.indexOf(previous)` if there will never be `-1` in the array? I tried this an it didn't work (check the update in my question).

Comment: @Michael `previous` is only initially -1. But later at each randomization it's being refreshed to the randomized value, see the line with the `console.log` where `previous` is assigned a value.

Comment: @Michael "didn't work" is to vague. How it didn't work for you? Have you tried my snippet in this answer before you made changes on it? Was it working inside this answer? If no, what was the problem?

Comment: @Michael edited my answer with a fix on your code. I mocked the sounds playing, because we are not testing whether sounds are played properly, but whether the randomization process is correct.

Comment: Thank you, it works. The issue was in the another code section that was interfering with the code above.

Answer (score 0):

You can maintain a history of played sound indices.  This will ensure that the newly selected sound index is different from the last one.

Here is a modified version of your code that implements this:

```
<template>
  <button class="book__nav-btn" @click="playTurnSfx">
    <slot></slot>
  </button>
</template>

<script setup>
import { ref, computed } from 'vue';
import Sfx1 from '@/assets/sounds/page-turn-1.mp3?url';
import Sfx2 from '@/assets/sounds/page-turn-2.mp3?url';
import Sfx3 from '@/assets/sounds/page-turn-3.mp3?url';
import Sfx4 from '@/assets/sounds/page-turn-4.mp3?url';
import Sfx5 from '@/assets/sounds/page-turn-5.mp3?url';

const sounds = [Sfx1, Sfx2, Sfx3, Sfx4, Sfx5];
const playedIndices = ref([]);
const lastPlayedIndex = computed(() => playedIndices.value[playedIndices.value.length - 1]);

const getRandomIndex = () => {
  let newIndex;
  do {
    newIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * sounds.length);
  } while (newIndex === lastPlayedIndex.value);
  return newIndex;
};

const playTurnSfx = () => {
  const newIndex = getRandomIndex();
  const sound = new Audio(sounds[newIndex]);
  sound.volume = 0.1;
  sound.play();
  playedIndices.value.push(newIndex);
};
</script>
```

This code has does the following / has the following modifications:

1. It maintains a `playedIndices` ref in order to keep track of the indices of the sounds that have been played.
2. The `getRandomIndex` function generates a random index.  It also makes sure that the new random index is different from the last played index using a do-while loop.
3. When the button is clicked, the `getRandomIndex` function is called in order to get a new random index, play the corresponding sound and add the index to the `playedIndices` array.